# Javascript (drop down function) vs TR tag

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-table, mapping

I would like to beautify my very old German / English business lexicon.
I thought, for a better view I will show and display the description only by a click on the section header.

So i find the Javascript code below.
Now, my big problem is, that the cell have after the Javascript mapping no more the desired design like "header2".

May anybody can help or can anyone suggest me something better?

My code:

```js
function spoil(id) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
  }
}
```

```css
.itabelle {
  border: 1pt solid black;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.ttype1 {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000000;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ttype2 {
  border-bottom: 0px dashed #000000;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13pt;
}
.ttype3 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table class="itabelle">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ttype1">german</td>
      <td class="ttype1">englisch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td class="ttype2" colspan="2" rowspan="1"><span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="spoil('id1');">header1<br>
    
    </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="id1" style="display: none;">
      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header1 (german)</td>

      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header1 (english)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ttype2" colspan="2" rowspan="1">Header2 (without javascript mapping)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header2 (german)</td>
      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header2 (english)</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Sorry in advance for chaos of html4/5 code.

Answer (score 0):

The normal `display` style for a `<tr>` is `table-row`. But your Javascript is setting it to `block` instead when it displays the row. Change it to use `table-row`.

```js
function spoil(id) {
  if (document.getElementById) {
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);
    divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'table-row' ? 'none' : 'table-row');
  }
}
```

```css
.itabelle {
  border: 1pt solid black;
  font-size: 12pt;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.ttype1 {
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #000000;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 16pt;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ttype2 {
  border-bottom: 0px dashed #000000;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: Arial;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13pt;
}
.ttype3 {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<table class="itabelle">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="ttype1">german</td>
      <td class="ttype1">englisch</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="1">
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td class="ttype2" colspan="2" rowspan="1"><span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="spoil('id1');">header1<br>
    
    </span>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="id1" style="display: none;">
      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header1 (german)</td>

      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header1 (english)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ttype2" colspan="2" rowspan="1">Header2 (without javascript mapping)</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header2 (german)</td>
      <td class="ttype3">lexicon article for header2 (english)</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: OMG! So simple and effective, thank you Barmar. I became 20 kilos lighter.